# How to make a list appear on click of a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a list to appear just below a button when I click the button.  It should look like it is unfolding out of the button.  When I click elsewhere, the list should disappear.

How do I accomplish this?

I have a ListView in my xml file.

Thanks!!

Comment: Dipti, can you edit your question and add the source code that shows your problem?  It's hard to help you without seeing some of your source code.